# intel XDK how to define permissions manully

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, appframework, intel-xdk

i'm developing app using XDK new editor and it contains a list which is update by JSON (getJSON).app working correctly with XDK Emulator.but not with real device. i want to know how to set network connection permission manually to the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the API you are using supports [JSONP](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/#jsonp), then use "callback=?" param (or whatever the callback name is) in the URL for $.getJSON(), then it should work on the real device.